# Is there any built-in method of channel_layer that returns the 'list of groups' in Django Channels?

Tags: django, chat, django-channels

I want to show the user the list of chatrooms opened in a real-time chat app built with Django-Channels. To do that a method which returns the list of groups made is needed since a group functions as a chatroom, I think. Is there any built-in method of chanel_layer that returns the list of groups? If not, is there another way to show the user the list of chatrooms opened?

**EDIT**: added 'since a group functions as a chatroom'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No since you could have many different instances of the server running there is no way to know what other instances have subscribed to.

For your situation I would suggest creating a Model in your database for a chat room.

You can then use this to list and use the `pk` from this in the channel group name when sending/subscribing to channel groups.

Comment: Thank you so much! The idea of creating a model for a chat room was really helpful.